# PHP: Why does preg_match give different results when it is inside a.html-file or a .php-file (unicode)?

Tags: php, unicode, preg-match

Recently I found preg_match giving different results when the PHP-code is inside a **.html**-file or a **.php**-file!

It seems like it has something to do with the RegEx-Modifier **"/u"**. When this flag is set and inside the teststring is an unicode-character(like the **"Ö"** in the examples),
it will give different results.

Does anyone have an idea why this could be?

**Example 1 - .html-file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <?php
    $test="asdddddAÖ";
    echo preg_match('/^[[:print:]\s]*$/u', $test);
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Example 1 - Output:**

> 0

**Example 2 - .php-file**

```
<?php
$test="asdddddAÖ";

echo "
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=\"en\">
    <head>
      <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      ".preg_match('/^[[:print:]\s]*$/u', $test)."
    </body>
    </html>";
?>
```

**Example 2 - Output:**

> 1

If I delete the unicode-character from the teststring the result of both is

> 1

which I expected.

Also if I delete the **/u**-Flag from the RegEx the result of both is

> 0

as expected too.

Both examples ran under the same apache-instance with php 5.6.24. And both files were encoded UTF-8 in the editor. It is also an Plesk 12 environment on Ubuntu 14.04 if that helps.

Comment: Are you sure both files have the same encoding?

Comment: What happens if you give the .phtml extension to the first file?

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk  Yea I am sure. Just checked it again and saved the files again.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, I obtain 1 in the two cases and 0 without the u modifier in the two cases too.

Comment: @DominiqueLorre - It appears, that apache is not set to interprete .phtml files ;-)

Comment: Try with .php then. I can't reproduce with php 7 and .phtml extension. If it does not come from the php version you'll need to look at the way .html is handled.

Comment: Run phpinfo() in both environments and check for differences

Comment: @ComputerPhysicsLab - Both examples ran under the same apache-instance with php 5.6.24. So same environment.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte , @DominiqueLorre -  Ok i checked the handlers in Plesk12 apache - PHP runs an FastCGI under FPM-Manager control. the handler directive is as simple as putting this line into .htaccess in the DocumentRoot `AddHandler php-script .html`